# Run code only between certain hours

Tags: php

I am trying to run a certain batch of code only during certain hours of the day. I want to run this code only after 8:00am and before 10:00 pm.

This code is included in the footer of my site, but it doesn't seem to be working, it is still running the code through these hours. (my server is in the same time zone as I am):

```
if(date("Hi") < 2200 && date("Hi") > 0800){
    // Run Code
}
```

How can I run the code only between the specific times?

Comment: Drop the leading `0` on `0800` and try it again.

Comment: Can't you just use a cron job to run it?

Comment: If you only know how to use an hammer, every problem will look like a nail.

Comment: or quote the times '2200' and '0800' to make it a string comparison

Comment: are you perhaps using a framework? Many frameworks have some functionality for this built in. WordPress for example has scheduled events which are an interesting cross between your attempt and a cron job BUT with respect for transactions and only running the  job once in a specified period.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(date("Hi") < 2200 && date("Hi") > 800){
    // Run Code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with strtotime function and relative formats:

```
if ( time() > strtotime( '08:00AM' ) && time() < strtotime( '10:00PM' ) ) {
    // run code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Ryan said up in the comments - You need to set this up as a cron job.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

to see your crons:

```
crontab -l
```

edit the crontab

```
crontab -e
```

an example cron that runs at 8am daily

```
00 08 * * * php path/to/script.php
```

The problem with setting it up the way you are attempting to is that every single request to your site is going to set off the event again (a possibility of mucking up the transactions)

Comment: The code he has is in the footer of his site (assuming he is showing something at a certain time). How will a cron solve that? He wants to show data between times, not run something at a certain time.

Comment: It actually is just adding a new post every 4 hours, which I want it to do only between the hours specified, so a cron job could surely be used in this situation. I just haven't used one before. I am using Webmin, any good tutorials you know of? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @webnoob he put the code in the footer not to add content to the footer, but to "run a certain batch of code only during certain hours of the day" which is pretty much exactly what a cron job is for. Also, he confirmed it with the comment above.

Comment: @FrancisYaconiello - My misunderstanding. Apologies. However, working on his orignial code means the code will run each refresh between those times. It's worth the OP clarifying if this should run once or more.

Answer (score 0):

just use "G" to get hours without leading 0

```
$time = date("Gi");
if(800 <= $time && $time <= 2200){
    // Run Code
}
```