# Add script in footer at specific hours of the day in php

Tags: php, wordpress, strtotime

I have a chat widget which only shows after 4 pm until 9 am (16:00 - 09:00).
The widget is being called in `wp_footer` via `<script>` tag with external `src=`.

I want to make sure this script is only loading during the specified hours of the day: 16:00 - 09:00 (next day), where it actually shows. When the widget doesn't show, there is no need to load the script.

I have managed to make this work using `strtotime` function and relative formats, from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840187/10497022).

```
function custom_script_loader_footer() {
  // Load only between 9:00 and 17:00.
  if ( time() < strtotime( '09:00AM' ) && time() > strtotime( '04:00PM' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script src="https://the-link-here" async></script>
    <?php 
  }
} 
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_script_loader_footer');
```

Above solution works, and the script is not loading between those hours.

My question is whether this is a correct way to do what I want to achieve?
Is it better to set this up as a cron job when it's a script, [as written here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839873/10497022)?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: you might run into issues where the client caches the page, and it does not update newly when loading your page. But generally doing this is the correct approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it some other way. Below is one of the way, kindly try it.

```
$hour = date('G');

function custom_script_loader_footer() {
  if ($hour >= 9 && $hour <= 16) {
    ?>
    <script src="https://the-link-here" async></script>
    <?php 
  }
} 
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_script_loader_footer');
```